# Internet Explorer displaying HTML audio player differently from other browsers

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, audio

I am new to ASP.NET web application building and I an using the HTML 5 `audio` tag to display an audio player for a user to use.

I am using the code below:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="BeatsDetails.aspx?beatID=<%#:Item.BeatID%>">
            <img src="/Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.BeatPath%>" width="75"  
            height="75" style="border: solid" />
            <br />
        </a>
        <br />
        <audio controls>
            <source src="/Beats/Kalimba.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
            <embed height="30" width="70" src="/Beats/Kalimba.mp3">
            <p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>
        </audio>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I run test the code on Firefox, Chrome and Safari and they show well.

[image]

However, in Internet Explorer 11, I get this where the audio players are huge and overlapping. How can I get it to show the same in IE as the other browsers?:

[image]

Comment: Controls have just different appearances in different browsers, you can't change it.

Comment: Does this mean I will have to make the spacings for the beats bigger so as to accomodate Internet Explorer? No other workaround?